# How to define a property on a utility type?

Tags: typescript, types, inferred-type

#### Attempting to get Type-inference Through Any Means Available

---

So I have a function that takes an array as an argument. The array contains unknown objects. We do know that the objects are all the same, so in other words, the array can only take one type of object, but that object type is dynamic, it can be almost anything. I say almost because we know one more bit of information: The objects all have a name property.

##### To Summarize:

---

The function's array parameter takes an array of objects that are all the same type, but the type is unknown. What we do know is that the type contains a name property, therefore; we know that every object has a name property.

#### Okay now lets look at the function:

---

```
type ObjType = {
  name: string;
  [key: string]: any;
}

type NewObj = {
  [key: string]: {}
}

export function nameArray(arrParam: ObjType[]){
  let obj: NewObj = {};

  arrParam.forEach((item, index)=>{
    obj[item.name] = item;
  });

  return obj;
}
```

##### About the Function & Types

---

Because we know that the objects all have a name property, we can use it to assign an appropriate name to a key, then assign the object to that key. This way we have our enumerable array, and an object that we can use to reference the objects by name.

##### The Function Works Wonderfully!

---

Okay, I lied, honestly I didn't mean to. The function does work, but I think wonderfully is a bad choice of wording. Type inference isn't flowing through the function, so, even though it works, I get no type info when I use it, which is a bummer, because TS is a lot of extra work, and whats the point if I don't wind up with types on the complex side of a script.

I am using it in a real project. This is the document I tested it on.

```
import { nameArray } from './util-fn.mjs';

type StrGenArg = {
    // INDEX @00
    name: string,
    arg: string,
    code: string | number;
  }

type StrGenArgs = StrGenArg[];

export const strGenArg: StrGenArgs = [
  { // INDEX @00 | "escOpen"
    name: 'escOpen',
    arg:  '%%',
    code: '\x1b'
  },
  { // INDEX @01 | "escClose"
    name: 'escClose',
    arg:  '%%',
    code: '\x1b'
  },
  { // INDEX @02 | "reset"
    name: 'reset',
    arg:  '0',
    code: 0
  },
  { // INDEX @03 | "red"
    name: 'red',
    arg:  '%r',
    code: 31
  },
  { // INDEX @04 | "green"
    name: 'green',
    arg:  'g',
    code: 32
  },
  { // INDEX @05 | "yellow"
    name: 'yellow',
    arg:  'y',
    code: 33
  }
];

export const args = nameArray(strGenArg);
```

As I said it works; like, I do the following.

```
console.log(args.yellow)
```

It prints yellow, same for red & green and the rest of the objects, however, as I said already: No Types!

I tried using a Utility Type like this.

```
function nameArray<T>(arrParam: T[]){
  let obj: NewObj = {};

  arrParam.forEach((item, index)=>{
    obj[item.name] = item;
  });
}
```

But when I write the function this way it doesn't know that **`T`** has a named property, consequently, TSC shows an error, and will not compile.

Is there anyway to write this function where I can get type inferrence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to constrain `T` to always have a property `name`. This will enforce that any element of the array passed to the function must have `name` property.

```js
function nameArray<T extends { name: string }>(arrParam: T[]){ /* ... */ }
```

But this does not fully fix your problem. You stated that you for example want to access `args.yellow`. So how can we do that?

This gets a bit complicated.

First we have to add `as const` to `strGenArgs`, so that we don't lose type information here:

```
export const strGenArg = [
  { // INDEX @00 | "escOpen"
    name: 'escOpen',
    arg:  '%%',
    code: '\x1b'
  },
  { // INDEX @01 | "escClose"
    name: 'escClose',
    arg:  '%%',
    code: '\x1b'
  },
  { // INDEX @02 | "reset"
    name: 'reset',
    arg:  '0',
    code: 0
  },
  { // INDEX @03 | "red"
    name: 'red',
    arg:  '%r',
    code: 31
  },
  { // INDEX @04 | "green"
    name: 'green',
    arg:  'g',
    code: 32
  },
  { // INDEX @05 | "yellow"
    name: 'yellow',
    arg:  'y',
    code: 33
  }
] as const;
```

We also introduce the generic type `K` which will hold all possible name values. Afterwards we return a `Record<K, StrGenArg>`.

```
type ExtractName<T extends { name: string }[]> = T[number]["name"]

function nameArray<
  T extends { name: string }[], 
  K extends ExtractName<T>
>(arrParam: readonly [...T]): Record<K, StrGenArg> {
  let obj: Record<string, any> = {};

  arrParam.forEach((item, index)=>{
    obj[item.name] = item;
  });

  return obj
}
```

Now the typing works:

```
export const args = nameArray(strGenArg);

args.yellow // works with typing
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=69&ssc=33&pln=67&pc=1#code/FDAuE8AcFMAIHkBGArAKlOBeWBvYtYA7AQwFtoAuWAZ1ACcBLQgcwG59YBtAa2nCtqMWAXSrFC4dgF8QEGLABy0AO5JksbHgI8%20A%20k2ajcMmWAywAogA96xAMagFZaAB5UsaDeiEAJtVxEznpCzLBSnMIAfBqwqJyEAK6kiNB0wpwARCTkGcIgAGYJhA4MAPaEgeQAgnR0xOBuHl6%20-jiVlDT6LGERADSwANJNoN5%20ljZ1Dk7kbpGRABTEtQAKS2RUdNDEPuUANuBcAHTHqMIAlFQAStB2pXQ%20LgP9AMr0AOLeNczRWrC70KBYKUUFcbncHoIDP1xOBopopOwOEs6Ks6qRDvk7hZ7AALebzBgjUj9Jg%20TxnTCRX4EYHITiE6Do7LQYQxBmkdgEKRnREETagBJ0Cq04CmMzyV50D6EL4xamwAD0CtgAEkFAARCwADVgAAEAAz6jgEZnBKHG2BLZhmli9C23Mk20IAHyISRSdE5YVk5kl0q%20-mwfs%20dGYEURnkgd0Bt0ItE6UpDoWwnA4bSVqo12r1htgroy0GodngMEIGQtptgAHJC8XS1W7QQCFaqNWAKRthv20qO6sAHSsAEZEFWOFJGwEM2rNTqDYO87AC0WAMK7UrUaDlpvtKg1ldrjdd7ctghVjtHpsOjpVgfD0dcifp5XT7MGgBMC4ymw3oC3TcrVbfgCF7NqGrZVvqIGwFeVBGg%20aaKs%20WazvqADMn6bD4f4mkE1aYVBJ7tnQUEwbAqGDmOj6IZmM45gALJ%20zCbN42E7tWTHQN4BFgaezAkT2HSoW%20lEIVOyE5gArJ%204DQLsa7KKxAEyXJpTKNx1qnuA-G9qhqFjsArLEP4sa0BGVhRnQMblPGVqBu0NR1OA8yCP6oY8iAtmHMp8nUcodzcP4yiEjisByAYQA)